# App freezes on textfield after iOS 14 update

Tags: ios, swift, freeze

after updating Xcode to Xcode 12 and upgrading my physical test device to iOS 14, I am having a peculiar problem with my app. I have two textfields for username and password, and if I fill out the username, and click on the textfield for password, the keyboard pops up but the apps CPU usage increases drastically to 99% and the app freezes. This has never happened before, and I haven’t made any changes that should cause this. I tested the same build on an iOS 12.4 and iOS 13.7 device, and they did not have the same issue. This seems to be happening only on iOS 14 devices. Another peculiar thing that happens is that if I fill out the password and then the username, the issue does not occur. I haven’t made any changes to textfields , the only thing that I am getting different from this build is that “archiveRootObject” has been deprecated. Could that maybe cause the issue here?

After debugging for a while I also found this weird message on Thread 1 “Application violated contract by causing UIApplicationMain() to return. This incident will be reported.” Has anybody faced this issue before?

EDIT: If I write a value in the username textfield, and then remove it, and then try to enter in password, the app works fine. Its only if the username textfield has a value before the password textfield has a value.

Comment: Are You using IQKeyboard pod?

Comment: No, I am however using the MaterialComponents framework to create MDCTextFields.

Comment: my solution was passwordField.autocorrectionType = .no
 mb it will help You too

Comment: Were you able to solve it @Shabani? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Sadly no, I am however in contact with Apple support. Hopefully they will be able to help!

Comment: @Shabani, updating MaterialComponents pod to the latest version (119) worked for me

Comment: I have similar freezes after keyboard is open on Xcode 12.2 and iOS 14.2 simulator. I think it is ok on a real device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many failed attempts at fixing the problem, and waiting for weeks until Apple answered my questions, the problem has finally been solved. It was actually just updating the "MaterialComponents" pod to version "119.1.0" that solved the issue. It took some time to update as we had problems with the pod but we eventually got it working. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Thank you. This has been driving me crazy and I thought it was something that I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this and restart your system

"Simulator -> Edit -> Automatically Sync Pasteboard" canel selected.
"Hardware -> Restart"

Device -> Restart

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work. The issue is also on a physical device. If I write a value in the username textfield, and then remove it, and then try to enter in password, the app works fine. Its only if the username textfield has a value before the password textfield has a value.